# how to compress multiple files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have make one software for compressing like this (.bak,.mdf,.mdb,.dmp,.ldb) types of files
but the problem is that compressing file one by one so that will be taking lots of time for
big file. So I want to compress multiple file at a time.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please review the [About] and [Ask] pages to get an idea on what sort of questions will get the best results from the site.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using .net 4.5, use native ZipArchive

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx

Answer (score 0):

DotNetZip is a FAST, FREE class library and toolset for manipulating zip files. Use VB, C# or any .NET language to easily create, extract, or update zip files. You can use 
[dotnetzip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)